# JQUERY/JSON data undefined, then defined mysteriously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a script that reads in some JSON data:

```
var tempJson;
$.post("scripts/getJSON.php", function(data) {
     tempJson = data;
}, 'json');
alert("");  //First alert
alert("That: " + tempJson);  //Second alert
```

When I include the first alert line, the second alert gives me an [Object object] as expected.  When I omit the first alert line, I receive undefined in the second alert.  Why?

Comment: You should use `console.log` because it doesn't stop execution of the script

Comment: try this:  tempJson = $.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 4):

Because it is asynchronous, and by the time you close the alert the ajax has been completed and the data returned and assigned to the variable.

You should

```
var tempJson;
$.post("scripts/getJSON.php", function(data) {
     tempJson = data;
     alert(tempJson); // or whatever you want to do with the data should go here..
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me to be a timing issue. You're firing off a request and then instead of checking the value in the callback you're checking right after the post script. AJAX is asynchronous ...aka **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**

```
var tempJson;
$.post("scripts/getJSON.php", function(data) {
     tempJson = data;

     // Callback here, response has most definitely happened
     alert(tempJson);
}, 'json');

// Response may not have happened yet when this is executed
alert("");  //First alert
// Still might not have happened when this is executed
alert("That: " + tempJson);  //Second alert
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX is by default assynchronous. So, if your request delay a bit your alert don't will have the request data. The correct is your call your alert in your callback.

Currently you can change AJAX request to synchronous, but it's deprecated by jQuery now and it hang up your browser. So the best way is your use success/complete/error callback/event of [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).